# How to efficiently render a list of fast changing data in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, rxdart

I have a stream of a fast-changing data:

```dart
final dataStream = Stream<List<int>>.periodic(
  const Duration(milliseconds: 30),
  (count) => List.generate(30, (i) => count + i),
);
```

And I want to perform a live update of the UI based on the new data:

```dart
class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: StreamBuilder(
          initialData: const <int>[],
          stream: dataStream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text(
                '${snapshot.requireData[index]}',
              ),
              itemCount: snapshot.requireData.length,
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Even though, this approach works I'm suffering from a frame rate drop (the app is running in the profile mode):
[image: Frame rate drop]

Thus, I was wondering what can be improved to make it more performant?

Comment: I'll suggest that You consider using Slivers